# Why would firefox display identical code differently?

Tags: css, firefox

I know. This is like claiming the compiler has a bug. Nevertheless, I am at a loss and need some explanation.

In my examples, I cannot post the source code as it is quite complex and probably proprietary. Also, please don't tell me there is something wrong with the design - it is the design I have to live with.

My problem is that there is a difference in how Firefox (Quantum/57) displays a page, depending on which site I am accessing. The code is exactly the same on both sites (*)

This is a snippet from the page, as displayed on the development site:

[image: development site]

This is approximately the same area, as displayed on the test site:

[image: test site]

Note, on the development site:

1. There is no border around the input field to the left
2. The checkboxes cannot be seen (if you give them focus there is the usual border around them, but they remain invisible even if checked or not)
3. The buttons have no background or border

Here is the development site as seen in Chrome/62:

[image: development site]

The development site and the test site looks the same in Chrome/62.

There is one difference between the development site and the test site, apart from the domain names of the sites: The test site is faster, due to better hardware. I cannot wrap my head around that this should be a timing issue, though.

I have disabled all browser extensions for both sites, cleared cache and reloaded. And then this:

(*) I know, I have been there, but I checked: Not only are the source files on the sites identical, I also compared all the files downloaded and used by Firefox (as seen in the Web Dev) for both sites and there was absolutely no difference, not even in the order they were downloaded.

**My question is**: What could cause this difference?

EDIT:

I compared all the files downloaded by the browser. All files were identical. Even the order they were loaded was identical. 
This includes the HTML, JS, CSS and (slightly desperately) the PNG files.

I used Web Dev in Firefox, Network tab and copied the content (for the HTML, JS and CSS files) from the Response tab into a text file. I then compared the text files with WinMerge. As the servers are both Windows servers and I have copied the files from the development site to the test site, I doubt that there could be problem with line endings or binary transfers.

EDIT (2):

The HTML is returned with an explicit encoding (iso-8859-1) but the .js and .css files are returned with an implicit encoding. I will check later if this is causing my problem.

EDIT (3) "closed":

Thank you to all that tried to help me here. Unfortunately, I *think* it was a problem in my browser and I *think* the problem was some sort of leak. Because, the problem disappeared in the new version of Firefox and before I upgraded, I noticed that it appeared to work shortly after restarting.

Comment: Did you compare the CSS and JS files?

Comment: Yes, I compared all the files downloaded by the browser. All files were identical. Even the order they were loaded was identical. EDIT: This includes the HTML, JS, CSS and (slightly desperately) the PNG files. EDIT2: How did I compare them? I used Web Dev in Firefox, Network tab and copied the content (for the HTML, JS and CSS files) from the Response tab into a text file. I then compared the text files with WinMerge.

Comment: Inspect the elements in developer tool, I am sure you are missing the image files or the entire folder or accidentally copied the folder to some other folder(happened to me once).

Comment: I have unfortunately already checked (and yes, that has happened to me before)

Comment: Those look like standard `inputs` and `buttons` and each browser renders those differently. A **reduced** demo wuld be appropriate.

Comment: Just a guess... you're using implicit encoding for .html and .css; chrome made a "correct" assumption(e.g. both utf-8) for both whereas ff didn't. i.e. check dev server if it responds  `Content-Type: text/css; charset=<your encoding, usually utf-8>`

Comment: I did not check this, so I will do some more testing next week. You are correct, the .js and .css files use implicit encoding (the .html is explicitly iso-8859-1) on both development and test. I had not thought to check if firefox might assume different encodings, so I will look into that.

Comment: @user943702 Nice catch